# how to overwrite devise controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the devise SessionController overwrited:

on app/controllers/customers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Customers::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_filter :destroy_cart, only: :destroy
    def destroy_cart
        cart = Cart.find(current_client.cart.id)
        cart.destroy
    end 

end
```

but the cart is never destroyed, even if I overwrite the destroy method directly and add the `super` after my code, the cart its still there, in the database (I knkow I could create the cart just once and get it when the user logs in again or create a new one when he use the app for first time, but I want to try it this way for now), is like if is not reading my code on that SessionController.

and for some reason even when I have my views this way:

`app/views/customer/registrations`

the changes that I do on that views are only reflected if I change it to

`app/views/devise/registrations`

my routes.rb is:

```
devise_for :clients, :controllers => { sessions: 'customers/sessions'}

devise_scope :client do 
    root to: "customers/Sessions#new"
end
```

the model that I am using with devise is `Client`
why I cant destroy the cart in the devise controller? 
and why I cant use the views/customer/sessions if the documentation it says I can/have to do it?

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always try to do

```
def destroy
  cart = Cart.find(current_client.cart.id)
  cart.destroy
  super
end
```

but first you might want to ensure that you really overwritten devise's controller correctly.

The reason why you can't see changes done to `app/views/customer/registrations` is beacuse you seems to overwrite only `:sessions` controller, so you need to change

`devise_for :clients, :controllers => { sessions: 'customers/sessions'}`

to

`devise_for :clients, :controllers => { registrations: 'customers/registrations', sessions: 'customers/sessions'}`

The last question is:

" why I cant use the views/customer/sessions if the documentation it says I can/have to do it? "

You have a typo here, you are using `customers` namespace, not `customer` in routes.rb [ `sessions: 'customers/sessions'` ] - just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Watch your spelling. The `before_filter` is calling a method that doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: thank you, but its not that, that was a mistke that I did when I wrote the code on here.